# How to delete posts which have same title?

Tags: title

Some of my posts duplicate title. How to delete them ? And keep only one.

Example: I have 4 post which have same title. And I want to delete 3 posts and keep one post. How to do this ?

Thank you very much ! Sorry for my poor English !

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you select them from the edit screen and delete them?

Comment: try this [Duplicate Posts Remover](http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-posts-remover/)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to look at the URLs of the posts (or the IDs) and determine what ones you'd like to delete. Then go to the all posts page and hover over the title of the post you'd like to delete, then click the red trash button.

Answer (score 0):

I would log in to phpMyAdmin if you have access. You can run a SQL query to find the duplicates and delete the older posts.

You have to fill in your prefix but this query will get you started. I would make a backup and read this article first http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/

You can not get your data back without a backup.

DELETE t1 FROM wp_posts t1
INNER JOIN wp_posts t2 
WHERE

t1.post_type = post AND t1.post_date < t2.post_date AND t1.post_title = t2.post_title;